# Vue.js не выводит изображение из объекта товара

Tags: vue.js

Почему не выводит картинку из поля image, где хранится путь? Как вывести изображение товара в таком случае?

```
<div class="col col-sm-4" 
                 v-for="product in products">
                 <img :src="product.image" alt="">
                <router-link tag="h3" :to="'/products/' + product.id_product">
                    <a>{{ product.title }}</a>
                </router-link>
                <div>{{ product.price }}</div>
                <button @click="addToCart(product)"
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        >
                    Add to cart
                </button>

            </div>
```

Comment: <img src="{{ product.image }}" alt="">

Comment: {{}} - можно прописывать только в шаблоне, а не в атрибуте

Comment: @AexFun, `product.image` точно путь к изображению? проверьте в консоли и откройте ссылку

Comment: Да, у меня абсолютный путь лежит {
   id_product: 1,
   count: 1,
   sum: null,
   title: 'Iphone 5',
   price: 20000,
   image: "https://ru.vuejs.org/images/logo.png"
  },

Comment: В консоле выводит img[data-v-60dfa932]

Comment: Перезапустил браузер - заработало.